# Custom Filter control in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

This may be a simple answer , I have a report which has a table of data. One of the columns in the data set is a 'project'. I want to create filter that when clicked will remove any rows with an empty cell in the project column. I can create a filter for the project column but it gives me a list of all projects in data set to filter. I just want a simple Yes/No type filter or button to click to only show data where the project field is populated and then can click back to include all.

I dont want this be a page filter as I want the option for user to include or exclude.

Comment: When you say empty, is it null or blank?

Comment: Yes sorry that's correct, Null or Blank

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to create a custom dimension to include or exclude the empty projects

```
 CASE 
 WHEN project IS NULL then "Blank Projects"
 ELSE "Other Projects"
 END
```

You could then use this as your filter by unticking the "Blank Projects" to exclude.